# Issue in Loading the url of images from DB and displaying them on .php page

Tags: php

i have uploaded the images to my system folder, through some php script, successfully, now what i want is that, to retrieve the images, the logic i implemented is this that i have uploaded the images to my system folder and save their urls to DB, now i am able to retrieve them from the DB, but unable to parse the URLS to "> tag, here is the code, URL'S are correct, because whenever i hit the URLS directly to my browser, images are shown in the Browser, any help will be awesome, here is my retrieving code.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else
      {
            mysql_select_db("uploading", $con);
            $sql_get=mysql_query("select * from imge");
            while ($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get))
                {
                    $img_urls=$db_field["link"];?>
                <img src="<?php echo $img_urls; ?>" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;border-style: solid;border-color: blue"/>
<?php
          }
      }
?>
```

Comment: What output do you receive when you execute `var_dump( $sql_get );`?

Comment: Does `$img_urls` contain a fully qualified, absolute URI? Is that URI really pointing to the image in question?

Comment: i have the tag 
                <img src="<?php echo $img_urls; ?>" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;border-style: solid;border-color: blue"/>
 its just showing borders which are being set

Comment: @hakre urls are perfect here is one which i m retreving C:/xampp/htdocs/PhpProject4/Project_Images/90603415558d56_Aurora_like_vista_style_by_mal93.jpg

Comment: is there any problem in parsing the url

Comment: The urls need to be relative to your webroot which probably isn't "C:/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the URLs relative to your webroot. Your webroot is the directory where the files you can access via `http://localhost/` (or `http://127.0.0.1`) are found.

So instead of:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/PhpProject4/Project_Images/90603415558d56_Aurora_like_vista_styl‌​e_by_mal93.jpg
```

Try something like:

```
/PhpProject4/Project_Images/90603415558d56_Aurora_like_vista_styl‌​e_by_mal93.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments, maybe (just maybe) you need to escape characters like '\' (I believe you have '\' instead of '/' in your windows environment). Also, it would be helpful to paste here the html output you got.

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
<img src="<?php echo $img_urls; ?>"
```

For:

```
<img src="$img_urls" ...
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I was blind. I had not seen the '?>' at 13th line. I use to make 'indented' code. I am not used to close that tag at that position. 

Sorry anyway. ;)